# Hitting port 80 on a local virtualbox server

Tags: ssh, port, virtualbox

I have a virtualbox server running on my local machine on port 2222.

I'm using it to test deploying my web app, so I'd love to be able to see if it was successfull on the virtual machine.

How do I hit port 80 on the virtual machine when the machine itself is running on port 2222 on my host laptop? Is there a way to specify a "double port" of sorts?

e.g.

```
# On my laptop host
curl localhost:2222:80
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by using port forwarding from your laptop to your virtual machine.  In your Vagrantfile, forward 80 from your guest to your host.  For example:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.define "vagrant" do |c|
    c.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest:80, host:80
  end
end
```

Then you should be able to `curl localhost:80`.  Or you can forward it to a different port on your laptop:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.define "vagrant" do |c|
    c.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest:80, host:8080
  end
end
```

and `curl localhost:8080`